# Rails: Is there any way to save a whole *.html.erb to a @Var?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form, after passing this form to the next page a preview of an Newsletter is generated. I want to pass the whole html of that preview to an @Var or to params. To save them later in Database and to send the Newsletter out. Is there any way to do that?

Cheers
Stefan

// EDIT: working now @status was not transferd in params, my mistake

THX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`render` (the default action) returns the rendered response. you can assign this to any variable you like:

```
@foo = render
```

`render` also assigns the rendered response to `self.response_body`. If you don't want this, you can use `render_to_string` instead:

```
@foo = render_to_string
```

Answer (score 0):

`render_to_string` will work, but it sounds like your overall architecture may be problematic. Why are you rendering to the DB, instead of rendering dynamically? Can you explain more about your use case?